# Easiest / recommended way of collecting data from clients

Tags: java, architecture, client-server

I like to write a Java application which I will give to my friends to collect some data. The data will be collected by me and I'm going to do some boring statistics. My friends are all over the place, the only link is the internet.

Now the question: **How do I collect the data?**

Simplest way I can think of is to generate an output file and let my friends send it back to me by e-mail. But it's not nice and sophisticated in a technical sense.

I also considered just sending some serialized data via a raw socket, but that will require a server with a proper receiving application. And writing such a thing which is exposed to the internet is no fun.

So for answers please consider the whole architecture, the client side as well as the server side.

Comment: How about a web service?  You don't have to worry about handling sockets if you use one of the many existing Java server environments.

Comment: That might be better than a plain server, yeah. But AFAIK tomcat and friends are also beasts... I don't have much experience in that field. I want something easy to setup and run. And it must be secure, whatever that means. (And a lot of other wishes to Santa ;) )
So when talking about sending by mail: I'm serious ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Google account I would offer the following two suggestions:

You could look into [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/). It offers a nice application environment, at no cost for reasonable usage. You could even restrict access to the application by authenticating with a google account and filter on your friends.

An other option would be to create a [questionnaire via Google docs](http://www.amisampath.com/2009/11/how-to-create-online.html). It will accumulate your friends answers into a spreadsheet which can be exported and processed offline via java.

Comment: App Engine sounds very nice... Regarding docs: can users also upload files in such a form, like CSV? (If you know, I can also try it out later) Because the java application that generates the data does not (just) ask the user for input but also acquires some system information and such stuff.

Comment: Uploading files is not an option for questionnaire in Google docs.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with dvberkel here on questionnaire. Don't try to make it more complicated than it should be. Just collect the data via Google Docs and then import that into Java and create your statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've commented on docs at dvberkel's answer.